# dynamic import in Nuxt3 results in TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier - but works when path is passed directly

Tags: dynamic, import, typeerror, nuxt3

### This works:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const data = await import('~~/myPath/myFile')
console.log(data)
</script>
```

### But this does **not** work:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const path = '~~/myPath/myFile'
const data = await import(path)
console.log(data)
</script>
```

It results in the error `TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier '~~/myPath/myFile'`

The server engine is *Nitro 1.0.0*, Nuet version is *3.0.0*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the reason: [Rollup security for file loading](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#imports-must-start-with--or-)

I got it to work like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const data = await import('../../../myPath/myFile.ts')
console.log(data)
</script>
```

And template literals work as well, such as

```
const pathName = "myPath"
const fileName = "myFile"
import(`../../../${pathName}/${fileName}.ts`)
```

The number of `../` depend on the file structure. It's relative to the path of the file, that is calling the `myFile.ts`